# AWS lex gives HTTP 500 error on calling lambda function as validation code hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

As the question says, I am getting a 500 error on the AWS lex chat terminal when using a lambda function as a validation codeHook. The lambda function is working and tested with a lex event and also the chatbot is working as expected and returning the slot values when not using a lambda function.

This is the exact error message given by lex

```
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
      <title>Page Error</title>
      <style>
        body {
          font: 13px/ 1.231 verdana, arial, helvetica, clean, sans-serif;
        }

        h1,
        .h1 {
          color: #E47911;
          font-size: 170%;
          font-weight: normal;
          margin: 1.5em 0 1em;
          padding: 0;
        }

        #errorPage {
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 44px;
          margin-bottom: 57px;
        }

        #errorPage h1 {
          margin: 12px 0;
        }

        #errorPage p {
          line-height: 1.7em;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="errorPage"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/webservices/console/500._V170950309_.gif" width="392" height="202"
          alt="500" />
        <h1>We're sorry!</h1>
        <p>An error occurred when we tried to process your request. <br /> Rest assured, we're working to resolve the problem as
          soon as possible. We apologize for the inconvenience. <br /> <a href="https://aws.amazon.com">Click here to visit our home page</a></p>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: This looks like a genuine error from Amazon, nothing to do with your configuration. Can you confirm if this problem has been resolved?